# Expand in Laurent series $f(z) = \frac{(z-2)}{ z^2 + 3z - 4}$ , by powers of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

-

Hello , i don't understand how to solve this function.
I just don't get it. If someone has more experience with Laurent series , I would be grateful to get an answer.

$f(z) = \frac{(z - 2)}{(z^2 + 3 z - 4)}$

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBTj0.png)

[what i've got so far , but i don't think that is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI6CI.png)

UPDATE #1:

Well , wrote the function as **$f(z) = \frac{A}{(z - 1)} + \frac{B}{(z + 4)}$**

then , i wrote **$z-2 = (A+B)z+4A-1B$**

then , i made a system of equations like

$A+B = 1$

$4A - 1B = -2$

and got that $a = \frac{-1}{5}$ and $b =\frac{6}{5}$ , so

$f(z) = \frac{-1/5}{z - 1} + \frac{6/5}{z + 4}$

Comment: What are you trying to do with Laurent series? Can you add any details of your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonce $0$ is not a singularity of your functions, your Laurent series is just a Taylor series. You started well:\begin{align}\frac{z-2}{z^2+3z-4}&=\frac15\times\frac1{1-z}-\frac65\times\frac1{4+z}\\&=\frac15\times\frac1{1-z}-\frac3{10}\times\frac1{1+\frac z4}\\&=\frac15\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n-\frac3{10}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^nz^n\end{align}if $|z|<1$.

Comment: how we get (3/4) * 1/(1+(z/4)) ?

Comment: @DorinMusteața There's no $\frac34$ in my answer.

Comment: Oh , i'm sorry , I mean , (3/10) * 1/(1+(z/4))

Comment: @DorinMusteața $$\frac65\times\frac1{4+z}=\frac65\times\frac14\times\frac1{1+\frac z4}=\frac3{10}\times\frac1{1+\frac z4}.$$

Comment: Final question , where from comes z/4 ? in third fraction , after 1/4

Comment: @DorinMusteața $4+z=4\times\left(1+\frac z4\right)$.

Comment: @DorinMusteața I'm glad I could help.